# Should an entity be persitent ignorant?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Should an entity be Persitent ignorant? What about the microsoft ADO.NET Entity Framorwok? Is it persistent ignorant?

Comment: "Should"? Depends on what framework you're using. EF uses POCOs which means they are persistent ignorant.

Comment: Did you even TRY reading the documentation ONCE before posting? They are pretty clear about that in the Entity Framework documentation,

Comment: Yes and its why I ask the question. I'm more interested by the answers here than by the documentation : what exactly people means by 'persistent ignorant'. They are ignorant of how they are stored but are they ignorant they can be stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity Framework supports both persistence ignorant, and persistence aware entities.

Previous answers suggest this is to with the generation pattern you use, this was historically true (by coincidence) but is no longer the case, both code first and database first generation patterns can chose to be persistence aware(ish) or persistence ignorant.

The decision for or against persistence ignorance in EF is a question of change tracking, how we detect changes which are occurring to entities and decide what actions are required to persist these to the database. EF has three main change tracking methods

- Snapshot tracking (entities are completely **persistence ignorant**)
- POCO proxy change tracking (entities **appear to be persistence ignorant** but behind the scenes are persistence aware)
- Self tracking entities (STEs) which are now deprecated (entities are **persistence aware**)

Persistence ignorance is all about allowing us to describe how our entities look without explicitly inferring they map to database tables. This means we are less rigidly tied to specific database implementations. However being persistence ignorant comes with some trade offs around how we efficiently communicate with the database.

If our entities are completely persistence ignorant we need to have our framework do a lot more work to understand when they change and what changes mean to our database. With Entity framework this comes by storing a side by side copy of all entities ever tracked (seen) by the context and doing a diff to detect changes.

With POCO proxies we create a mock extension of the original entity and listen in to operations on specific properties so we can track changes much more efficiently.

The EF team has done a pretty amazing job on the snapshot change tracker to allow us to have completely persistence ignorant entities. This performs really well in small contexts (where we are tracking less than 1k objects at a time) but in cases where this perhaps doesn't fit our usage they have provided alternate tracking methods.

Even with pure POCO entities and snapshot tracking we have different levels of persistence ignorance depending on if we decide to use attribute decoration or the model builder to configure the exact details of our mapping to SQL tables. This is one of the key reasons I am a big fan of using the model builder over attribute decoration.

In answer to your title question *'Should an entity be persitent ignorant?'* my opinion is ideally yes, but only where it practically makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

EF is storage system agnostic yes. You can  write your own provider if you want.  eg a memory based storage model.  There is a provider model EF expects.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789835.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Generically speaking, your entity objects should be simple data holders. They should not care where the data comes from, how it is obtained, or where it goes, their job is as a container for a related set of data points (a record if you will). There are normally other objects (data access objects) whose job it is to obtain the data and populate entity objects with it, or to take an entity object and save it's data to the data store.